# SQL Server 2005 mdf file on 2012

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012-express

I have a SQL Server 2005 `.mdf` file I need to install on a server. Can I simply install SQL Server 2012 Express and attach the `.mdf` file without any issues, or should I stick to 2005 Express to eliminate any issues that may arise?

I should also add it needs to support a ASP.NET 3.5 website.

Cheers

Comment: As long as the `.mdf` file isn't too big (the **Express** editions have a 10 GB size limit), you should have no issues. Just remember: once you've attached that `.mdf` to SQL Server **2012** - you **cannot go back** anymore - you cannot detach that 2012 `.mdf` file and re-attach it to 2005 anymore. The upgrade path is just one way - up, to newer version - but never back "down" to older versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all files (mdf, ldf and potentially multiple ndf) and the database was cleanly shut down, you won't have an issue attaching to 2012.

If you have only the mdf it might work but it could also fail.

Either way, first take a backup of the files you have.

That being said, make sure you don't use any features that changed between 2005 and 2012 (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532.aspx for details)

Comment: Where can I download 2005 express installer. I cant seem to find it anywhere?