# old mdf file vs newer versions of sql server express

Tags: version, sql-server-express, mdf

I have an old mdf file originating from sql server express 2005.  I want to port/run my old project on my Win 7 SP1 64-bit machine. I don't have any version of SQL server express installed yet.

Should I go for the oldest version of SQL server express that can run on my machine (sql server express 2008 R2 SP1) or for the newest version (sql server express 2014 SP1), or in between ?

I would rather install a newer version of SQL server express, but I do need my old 2005 mdf file to be accepted/upgraded when I try to re-create the database.

Thanks !
JF

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there should not be a problem if you attach mdf directly or use a backup file. 
Please check out answer here: [SQL Server 2005 mdf file on 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506382/sql-server-2005-mdf-file-on-2012). This talks about 2005 to 2012, but should be a similar process.